# Angular ui-router nested views - No content appears

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I'm trying to implement nested views for a page using angular ui-router and have configured the state definitions matching various tutorials, but can't get any content to show up for the child views, despite having no errors in the console.

I'm trying the following with parent.child dot notation for the state names:

```
.state('employees/employeeDetails', {
        url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:id',
        templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails/employeeDetails.html',
        controller: 'employeeDetailsController',
        resolve: {
            lazyLoad: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/controllers/employees/employeeDetails/employeeDetailsController.js');
            }
        }
    })

    .state('employees/employeeDetails.mainDetailsTab', {
        url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:id/mainDetails',
        templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails/mainDetailsTab.html',
        controller: 'mainDetailsTabController',
        resolve: {
            lazyLoad: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/controllers/employees/employeeDetails/mainDetailsTabController.js');
            }
        }
    })
```

-

HTML:

```
<div id="mainContent" data-simplebar>

  <div ui-view="mainDetailsTab" id="mainTab" class="tabContent carousel-item employeeDetailsTab"></div>

  <div ui-view="paymentsTab" id="paymentsTab" class="tabContent carousel-item employeeDetailsTab"></div>

  etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redefine the entire path to the url property, just put the addition.

In this case: `url:'/mainDetails'`

Comment: Ok, I see that you re also missing the "views" property, which should look like (in your child view):

`views: {
        'mainDetailsTab': {
          templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails/mainDetailsTab.html',
          controller: 'mainDetailsTabController'
        }
      }`

Comment: That's another way of doing it, which I've already tried as well. I'm not 'missing' it, it's just another method which equally doesn't work

Comment: Would you create a plunkr?

Comment: I can, but to replicate this is going to take ages

Comment: Have you tried to console.log something in your child resolve method?

Comment: I've tried to log a message into the console within the mainDetailsTab resolve, but it's showing 'unreachable code after return statement'. However, lazy load is saying in the console that the file has been loaded correctly

Comment: Sorry but nothing is working in the plunkr. I will have no time to pursue this investigation but I would recommend you to get rid of the superfluous (lazyLoad) and to simply your namings (no slash in state names) and to try with views prop mentionning the ui-view value. Good luck!